# Premature end of script headers in perl scripts

Tags: perl, apache, cgi, handler

I have problem in execution of perl scripts. I am using `Alias` for the directory of the server like that:

```
Alias /epbin3/  /opt/v-hosts/user/epbin/
<Location /epbin3>
   AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
  # SetHandler cgi-script
  # SetHandler perl-script
  # PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::PerlRun
   Options All
  AllowOverride None
</Location>
```

When I'm trying to execute any perl file the browser return error 500.the error shown below:

```
[Sun Jun 09 15:50:19 2013] [error] [client ipClient] Premature end of script headers: searchHotelsTh4.pl
[Sun Jun 09 15:50:22 2013] [error] [client ipClient] (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/opt/v-hosts/epilgrim/epbin/searchHotelsTh4.pl' failed
```

Please anyone can tell me what's the problem and how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Can you show the code that calls the script?

Answer (score 0):

If I guess correctly than you have no Directory directive which allows the file access to the file system:

```
<Directory /opt/v-hosts/user/epbin/>
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
    Options All
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Comment: I got the same error message<br> `[Sun Jun 09 16:43:22 2013] [error] [client ipClient] (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/opt/v-hosts/user/epbin/map/landmarks.pl' failed
[Sun Jun 09 16:43:22 2013] [error] [client ipClient] Premature end of script headers: landmarks.pl
 `

Comment: Does a `/opt/v-hosts/epilgrim/epbin/searchHotelsTh4.pl` exits at that position? Check also that file `/opt/v-hosts/user/epbin/map/landmarks.pl`. Please check double the case sensivity.

Comment: when I remove the AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl the file searchHotelsTh4.pl can be readable as text in the browser but I get this error when I active the handler

Comment: IMHO the interesting part is that the error has changed to another file after you add my directory directive it seems to be a perl problem. Does it work if you execute the perl script from command line?

Comment: when Iam trying to execute perl files using command line the result show on the command screen without problems.I made small test file contain the following `#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;
use strict;
print "Muneer";`  it print Muneer that means the perl executed the file

Comment: That proves nothing except that `perl` in general works on your system. Do your actual scripts work OK if run from the command line?

Comment: This is function call the script using Alias epbin2         `function ajaxSearchHotelsTest(div){
 var targetDiv = div ;
    var url = '/epbin2/searchHotelsTh4.pl?';
 errorMsg = 'Sorry an error occurred while searching hotels.\n Refresh the page to try again.';
 errorHTML = 'No hotels were found.';
 getAjaxData(url,targetDiv);
}`

Answer (score 0):

A properly formed HTTP reply contains a blank line between the headers and the body.  It is likely that `searchHotelsTh4.pl` is lacking such a blank line, either because it does not output headers at all or the blank line is missing, i.e. you might have this:

```
Content-type: text/plain
Hello, world!
```

when you need this:

```
Content-type: text/plain

Hello, world!
```

Comment: I think this is highly unlikely to be the issue. "Premature end of script headers", in Perl CGI-land, usually just means "your script didn't reach the point where it sends output to the browser" -- you have to look at the subsequent error message to debug it.

Comment: Thank you alot but how I can look for subsequent error message in perl using putty.Iam looking for error log and I got this message only "Premature end of script headers".If there is any another error log to look for it?

Comment: Is the problem very complex ? Until now I don't fid any solution ?

Comment: This is function call the script using Alias epbin2         `function ajaxSearchHotelsTest(div){
 var targetDiv = div ;
    var url = '/epbin2/searchHotelsTh4.pl?';
 errorMsg = 'Sorry an error occurred while searching hotels.\n Refresh the page to try again.';
 errorHTML = 'No hotels were found.';
 getAjaxData(url,targetDiv);
}`